# thecartpress navigation tree

Tags: jquery, wordpress, categories, product

I have used thecartpress plugin in wordpress to create a catalog of products and their categories. I am using jquery to automatically open up selected category as in (http://demo.homoeo4u.com/product_category/commercial/) . But on this page which is single product page http://demo.homoeo4u.com/product/1cl59-series/ how do i show current category highlighted and tree opened up ?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: You have error in your jquery code. please check the console.

Comment: I edited the code now it does not have that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is getting executed before your page is getting loaded.Wrap your jquery code inside document ready block.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   jQuery('.tcp_navigation_tree a:contains("'+category+'")').next('.children').show();
})
```

Comment: I have made changes to code.. On single product page i need to show related categories ..

Comment: It's not working cause your `category` variable contains product name. It should contain the category name. To get the category name change your permalink structure to the following:
http://demo.homoeo4u.com/product/CATEGORY/1cl22-series/